# Multiple site on apache 2

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-22.04

i have a apache 2 installed on my ubuntu 22.04 server, the server the server was working with multiple sites configured with http://ip_address/site_name and every site was in /var/www/html/site_name .

After an bad installion of another site i lost the configuration of apache and i would like to reconfigure a site as previous config.

Is there somebody that can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if you don't have a backup you can restore, you can always start from scratch ... I mean, you managed to get it working before you broke it - you could always post your config and someone may be able to tell you how you broke it

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. This is a forum for questions and answers. If you want guidance on how to solve an issue then you should post the relevant details of the issue in your question. Use the comments for clarification of any answers you disagree with or don't understand.